# How to efficiently get short array from resources on Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, resources

I've got an XML file storing an array of shorts in my resources. I need to assign this array, but Android API only provides a way to get array of ints (`getResources.getIntArray()`). I've ended up getting an array of ints and converting it to array of shorts later, but that's hardly ideal.

Is there a way to get an array of shorts from Android resources? If not, is there a more efficient/cleaner way of converting int array into short array? My code currently looks like this:

```
int indicesInt[] = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.indices);
short indices[] = new short[indicesInt.length];
for (int i = 0; i < indicesInt.length; i++) {
    indices[i] = (short)indicesInt[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to directly retrieve an array of shorts AFAIK. It would be worth it to see if you can just use an `int[]` in place of your `short[]`. If you're using a library or something and can't change the requirement, your example is pretty much the best way to do it. Be wary of possible overflow.